# Cow tipping robot plans

Tags: design, mobile-robot

Does anyone have plans for a cow tipping robot? Its hard to do by hand so we are thinking a robot would be good. I remember seeing a robot wars or some other show where one bot tried to tip another, does any have a link to about that?

Comment: Are you thinking remote-controlled or completely autonomous?

Comment: If it was easier to tip a cow then it would be less fun to do.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, automated cow tipping can be done by a simple programmable calculator or smartphone app.  It doesn't take the complexity of a robot to calculate the normal 15-20%.  If the milk is particularly good, 25% is not unreasonable.  Chocolate Milk or Egg Nog, if completely natural and direct from the cow, deserves 50%!

The practice of cow tipping, sneaking up on a sleeping cow and pushing it over, is a complete urban legend.  For starters, a cow sleeps lying down and is quite hard to push over when it is already on the ground.  It only rests while standing up, and is quite alert in that state.  You are not likely to sneak up on a resting cow, much less push it over.

Even if it did work, you would be pushing over a 1,000+ pound animal and that does not come without consequences.  First, there is the real possibility of injury to the animal (falling on something pointy, hard, or sharp).  Second, there is a big chance for damage and/or injury to things or animals near the cow.  Third, there is also a big chance for injury to YOU.  Cows seem dumb and docile, but they can run fast, weigh a lot, and especially mothers and bulls will have no reservations to run you down.  Fourth, the result of the first two consequences can/will/should result in a criminal record for you.

Comment: I am so happy that someone else in the world is smart enough to comprehend that cows do not sleep standing up. I grew up on a small farm in IL, and this notion drives me nuts every time I hear it. Now horses do 'sometimes' sleep standing up. I've been kicked by a heifer before, but I can't imagine getting booted by a p'd off horse, protective cow, or territorial bull.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier but how do you know those cows were sleeping and not previously tipped by a stealth cow tipping robot?

Comment: @PeterJ I suppose I don't...